# How to use xlim to shape x-axis in python

Tags: python

I've read about some Questions concerning this, but I couldn't figure out...

I want to make my CDF graph just show me the x range of 0~120
The problem is xlim raise error of invalid syntax..
Any suggestion or hing would be very appreciated because this is the first thing I do in python.

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.load('C:\\Users\\python\\Desktop\\abnormal.npy')
# Choose how many bins you want here
num_bins = 20

# Use the histogram function to bin the data
counts, bin_edges = np.histogram(data, bins=num_bins, normed=True)

# Now find the cdf
cdf = np.cumsum(counts)

# And finally plot the cdf
plt.plot(bin_edges[1:], cdf)
xlim([0 120])
plt.show()
```

Comment: you need a comma between the two values

Comment: also suspect that xlim will not be defined => plt.xlim

Comment: Thanks a lot, the document example was "xlim[min max]" but comma in needed